# Simple JavaScript encryption & decryption without using key

Tags: javascript, encryption

I would like to know if it is possible to encrypt and decrypt a text, using pure JavaScript. **I don't want to use a key**. It may be an entry lever solution. But I simply want to encode a text "my-name-1" into some text format and want to retrieve the text from it. Is this possible, **without using any js libraries**?

Comment: Base64, Rot13, etc come to mind... hardly "encryption" though.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Without a key (or some secret for that matter), you wont get any kind of encryption.

What you mean is something like a different encoding. So maybe Base64 is something for you.

```
var baseString = 'my-name-1';

var encodedString = window.btoa( baseString ); // returns "bXktbmFtZS0x"

var decodedString = window.atob( encodedString );  // returns "my-name-1"
```

This is [supported in all major browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.btoa#Browser_Compatibility). IE support just in IE10+.

References:

- [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)
- [`window.btoa()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.btoa)
- [`window.atob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.atob)

Answer (score 1):

In my case (storing a game score) I needed to add a bit of obfuscation on top of base64 encryption:

```js
const z = ['a', 'o', 'b', 't']
const y = z[0] + z[3] + z[1] + z[2]
const x = z[2] + z[3] + z[1] + z[0]
function encrypt(str) {
  return window[x]?.(str).split('').reverse().join('')
}

function decrypt(str) {
  return window[y]?.(str.split('').reverse().join(''))
}
```

This is ok for my case because:

- I don't need real encryption
- The word `btoa` is not searchable in the code
- The outputted string is not clearly base64 and decoding it will fail
- Makes harder (but not impossible) for the user to cheat

**Disclaimer**: **This is not encryption** and shall not be used for security purposes, this is obfuscation